# ssh "connection timed out" after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi

I got an Raspberry Pi 4 4GB running Ubuntu 21.04 Desktop. I want to connect via ssh to my Raspberry Pi Zero (without Wireless) running Raspbian lite.
For the ssh setup i followed the instructions stated here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66431/headless-pi-zero-ssh-access-over-usb
I have done the configuration on the Zero and added a usb0 file to ^path_to_mounted_sd^/rootfs/etc/network/interfaces.d/ containing following lines:

```
allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
address 192.168.137.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.137.0
broadcast 192.168.137.255
gateway 192.168.137.1
```

Afterwards i plugged the Zero in the usb port at my Pi 4 and waited until the boot process finished. I set a static ip to the interface of the Pi4 as well. Also i set the Network IPv4 Settings to link local only. Tried to ssh into the zero and it worked. I scp'ed a python scriped to the zero. This worked as well. To run the skript i need to install the picamera module to the zero. I tried this but it didn't work (could not connect to the servers). I unplugged the Zero and rebooted it.
Now the problem after unplugging and rebooting i couldn't connect to the Zero via ssh. Error: Connection timed out.

Has anyone an idea how this problem can occur? Is it because of unplugging the zero? Does anyone know a solution for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem!
It seems that you need to specify through what interface you want to connect to this specific IP Adress. Recongnized that when I had switched of my wifi and I got the error: Could not reach network.

So when you specifiy the interface for the IP like this:

```
sudo route add -host <your-ip-address> dev <your-desired-interface>
```

it works for me.

Example: `sudo route add -host 192.168.133.4 dev enx2a93ffaf3472`